# Java/Tomcat Web Service, Possible memor leak or GC tuning needed

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, mahout-recommender

I have a web service running on Tomcat 8/Windows. It processes a large amount of data loaded into memory. Task Manager shows the Tomcat process occupying ~9G after the initial data load; Tomcat's max memory pool is set to 14G.
Visual GC shows 4.5G of Old Gen memory used on initial data load.

When I start testing the service with a moderate stable load the amount of used Old Gen memory remains more or less stable for some period with minor growth. GC activity is at ~0.5%.

At some point (sometimes after 10 min, sometimes after about 1h) the Old Gen memory usage starts to grow rapidly and reaches ~8.9G of 9.3G available. VisualVM monitor shows GC consuming ~10% of CPU, total CPU load reaches 100%. GC works for about 2 min and sometimes the Old Gen memory usage drops to the initial value (4.5G) but sometimes it remains the same (9G) after the GC run. In the latter case after pressing the "Perform GC" button in VisualVM the Old Gen memory usage drops to the initial value (4.5G).

### Some Mahout-specific details

I observe a significant grow of the amount of the objects `GenericUserPreferenceArray` and `GenericUserPreferenceArray$PreferenceView` when Old Gen usage starts to grow rapidly.
At the same time the amount of `long[]` and `float[]` arrays almost doubles.

```
                            On initial load    Stable Old Gen     Grown Old Gen
                            Bytes  Instances   Bytes  Instances   Bytes  Instances
long[]                      2.2G   27.5M       3.2G   27.5M       3.8G   52.4M
float[]                     0.9G   27.5M       0.9G   27.5M       1.6G   52.4M
GenericUserPreferenceArray  0.6G   21.5M       0.6G   21.5M       1.3G   43.0M
PreferenceView              0.5G   23.2M       not in top 10      0.7G   32.0M
Object[]                    0.4G    2.6M       0.6G    4.3M       0.9G    6.6M
GenericItemPreferenceArray  0.2G    6.1M       0.2G    6.1M       0.3G    9.4M
```

Do I observe the symptoms of a memory leak or should I somehow tune garbage collection?